# How to make full matrix from dense pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas df in the form:

```
   A  B    C
0  2  1  428
1  4  3   14
2  5  5  177
```

I wish to have an array, where A are rows, B columns and C values - the tricky part is the array should be full, in sense of indices, so:

```
[[  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [428.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.  14.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0. 177.]]
```

and remaining places are filled with zeros. 
I can do that with series of for loops, but is there any smart way of doing it?

Comment: I don't know who edited it, but thank you very much for help - sorry for mistakes, it's my very first time here

Comment: "the tricky part is array should be full, in sense of indices" can you please elaborate on this

Comment: Don't foget accpet an answer:) https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work @user12774760

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the method `put` in `numpy`:

```
arr = np.zeros((df['A'].max(), df['B'].max()))

idx = (df['A'] - 1) * df['B'].max() + (df['B'] - 1)
arr.put(idx, df['C'])
```

Output:

```
[[  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [428.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.  14.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0. 177.]]
```

If you need a matrix where indices start at zero:

```
arr = np.zeros((df['A'].max() + 1, df['B'].max() +1 ))

idx = df['A'] * (df['A'].max() + 1) + df['B']
arr.put(idx, df['C'])
```

Output:

```
[[  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0. 428.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.  14.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0. 177.]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with [`DataFrame.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
s = df['A'].append(df['B'])
r = range(s.min(),s.max()+1)
#r = range(1,6) if you want select a specific range
new_df =( df.pivot(index = 'A',columns = 'B',values = 'C')
           #.pivot(*df) #or this
            .reindex(index = r,columns = r)
            .fillna(0)
            .rename_axis(columns = None,index = None) )

print(new_df)
       1    2     3    4      5
1    0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0    0.0
2  428.0  0.0   0.0  0.0    0.0
3    0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0    0.0
4    0.0  0.0  14.0  0.0    0.0
5    0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  177.0
```

**Get an array**

```
new_df.to_numpy()
#new_df.values
array([[  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [428.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,  14.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0., 177.]])
```

Comment: Yes, that's perfect, thank you very much, kind stranger

Answer (score 1):

I have found one more way to solve this:

```
from scipy import sparse

sparse.coo_matrix((df['C'], (df['A'], df['B']))).toarray()
```

Output:

```
array([[  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0, 428,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,  14,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 177]])
```