# How to transform multiple pandas dataframes to array in memory constrains?

Tags: python, pandas, bigdata

The given problem:
I have folders named from folder1 to folder999. In each folder there are parquet files - named from 1.parquet to 999.parquet. Each parquet consist pandas dataframe of given structure:

```
id   |title   |a
1    |abc     |1
1    |abc     |3
1    |abc     |2
2    |abc     |1
...  |def     | ...
```

Where column **a** can be value of range a1 to a3.

The **partial** step is to obtain structure:

```
id | title | a1 | a2 | a3
1  | abc   | 1  | 1  | 1
2  | abc   | 1  | 0  | 0
...
```

In order to obtain **final** form,:

```
    title
id | abc | def | ...
1  | 3   | ... |
2  | 1   | ... |
```

where values of column **abc** is sum of columns a1, a2 and a3.

The goal is to obtain final form calculated on all the parquet files in all the folders.

Now, the situation I am now looks like this: I do know how to receive the final form by partial step, e.g. by using sparse.coo_matrix() like explained in [How to make full matrix from dense pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895012/how-to-make-full-matrix-from-dense-pandas-dataframe) .

The problem is: due to memory limitations I cannot simply read all the parquets at once.

I have three questions:

1. How to get there efficiently, if I have plenty of data (assume each parquet file consists of 500MB)?
2. Can I transform each parquet to final form separately and THEN merge them somehow? If yes, how could I do that?
3. Is there any way to skip the **partial** step?

Answer (score 1):

For every dataframe in the files, you seem to

- Group Data by the columns `id`, `title`
- Now, sum the data in column `a` for each group

Creating a full matrix for the task, is not necessary and so's the `partial` step.

I am not sure, how many unique combinations of `id`, `title` exists in a file and or all of them. A safe step would be to process files in batches, save their results and later combine all results

Which looks like,

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import string

def gen_random_data(N, M):
    # N = 100
    # M = 10

    titles = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: ''.join(x), 1, np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_lowercase), 3*M).reshape(-1, 3))
    titles = np.random.choice(titles, N)
    _id = np.random.choice(np.arange(M) + 1, N)
    val = np.random.randint(M, size=(N,))

    df = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack((_id, titles, val)).T, columns=['id', 'title', 'a'])
    df = df.astype({'id': np.int64, 'title': str, 'a': np.int64})

    return df

def combine_results(grplist):
    # stitch into one dataframe
    comb_df = pd.concat(dflist, axis=1)

    # Sum over common axes i.e. id, titles
    comb_df = comb_df.apply(lambda row: np.nansum(row), axis=1)

    # Return a data frame with sum of a's
    return comb_df.to_frame('sum_of_a')

totalfiles = 10
batch      = 2
filelist   = []
for counter,nfiles in enumerate(range(0, totalfiles, batch)):
    # Read data from files. generate random data
    dflist = [gen_random_data(100, 2) for _ in range(nfiles)]

    # Process the data in memory
    dflist = [_.groupby(['id', 'title']).agg(['sum']) for _ in dflist]

    collection = combine_results(dflist)

    # write intermediate results to file and repeat the process for the rest of the files
    intermediate_result_file_name = f'resfile_{counter}'
    collection.to_parquet(intermediate_result_file_name, index=True)
    filelist.append(intermediate_result_file_name)

# Combining result files.
collection = [pd.read_parquet(file) for file in filelist]
totalresult = combine_results(collection)
```